# How to call a function automaticlly when exit a java program?

Tags: java

I have a static function to save the high score! I wonder is there a easy way to call this function automaticlly when we exit a program.
If in C++, I can put this function in destructor and it works.
But in java I dont know how!
Any idea to do this?
Thank you!

Comment: Use Google next time.

Comment: And what is your program? Is it command line? Is it a GUI program?

Comment: @Kon you probably don't want to use a JVM exit hook if you run a GUI; rather, you want to plug into the window close event.

Comment: @fge Mostly yes, but that won't fire if the process is terminate through a kill -9 or taskkill, for example.

Comment: @Kon neither will a JVM exit hook :p

Comment: @fge Ah, wasn't aware. That makes sense actually. But at least this case covers all GUI types as well as console programs. But a Listener would be cleaner.

Comment: Thanks. I will do a reseach. Its a game...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all kind of java applications, you could **REGISTER A SHUTDOWN HOOK**, like this:

```
   Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    System.out.println("Your job when app shutdown");
   }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, but where I can add that function?

Comment: At the beginning of your program. It will register the hook, and it will automatically runs the code when the time comes.

Comment: If it works for You, then vote my post up, and mark as the right answer, so others would find this solution easier.

Answer (score 0):

for **Swing** **GUI** programs

```
myform.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {

            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                    // your exit codes here
                    System.exit(0);
            }
        });
```

Comment: That's for swing; for JavaFX it will be different

Comment: I am a swing guy :), Thanks for the hint, @fge